# Developing locally using express, mongodb and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently making an app using express, mongodb and mongoose, and I'm running it locally on my machine. My problem is that if I'm not connected to the internet the app won't run at all due to the app not being able to connect to mongodb server.

I thought that if I ran the mongodb server locally on my computer along with the app then I wouldn't need an internet connection, or is my understanding wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's correct. You'll just need to make sure you point your app at the local mongodb instance.

Comment: You possibly might have dependencies  still connecting to the internet instead of being served locally. Quite hard to say the actual reason with info provided.. at what point or how do u know that it's issue with db connection . Any error logs?

Comment: Just to clarify with dan is this pointing at my local mongodb instance "mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping');".                        And in reply to searching, it logs "MongoError: failed to connect to server on port....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: yes.

If you install MongoDB locally then you won't need internet connection to access it.

Make sure that your connection string contains "localhost".

Also, make sure that you don't need anything else on the internet, and that you run `npm install` while you are connected to the internet, or otherwise your dependencies (like mongoose) won't get installed. After they are installed they can work without the internet connection just fine - if your database is on localhost.

Also, make sure that your local MongoDB server is running. You can run:

```
mongo test
```

in the command line to see if you can connect to a local database.

Answer (score 1):

You're in the right path !

Here's the thing, you need to get yourself a copy of MongoDB, you can download and install the suitable version to your system from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community).

Now you need to configure MongoDB in your in your path so you can launch it when you is or simply add it a process that will launch when your system starts.

In order to configure please choose the suitable conf to your system :

1. [Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).
2. [Linux](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/).
3. [macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/).

Then, before running your application, make sure MongoDB is running in the background ad service or daemon and then simply launch your application.